# How to evaluate the integral $\int_{-1}^{0}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt{1+x}}}}}dx=?$

Tags: definite-integrals, closed-form, nested-radicals

We have  :

$$\int_{-1}^{0}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+x}}}dx=\frac{8}{315}\sqrt{2}\Big(16+\sqrt{233+317\sqrt{2}}\Big)$$

We are lucky because this integral have an anti-derivative like [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inegral%20&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Integral%22%2C%20%22rangestart%22%7D%20-%3E%22-1%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C%20%22inegral%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Integral%22%2C%20%22integrand%22%7D%20-%3E%22sqrt%281%2Bsqrt%281%2Bsqrt%281%2Bx%29%29%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Integral%22%2C%20%22rangeend%22%7D%20-%3E%220%22).

More seriously I have tried the following substitution :
$x=((t-1)^2-1)^2-1)^2-1$

We get a big polynomial easily integrable .

But what about the following integral :
$$\int_{-1}^{0}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt{1+x}}}}}dx=$$

Have you other technics to evaluate this ?

Thanks in advance for your contributions !

### Update :

As it seems to be unclear I ask for a finite number of nested radical.Furthermore it's not an innocent question because I know that it converges to the golden ratio .The imlpicit question is : How to get nested radicals near from the value of the golden ratio ?

Thanks again.

Comment: Why can't you use the exact same kind of substitution?

Comment: @LeeMosher I ask if there is other method more practical than mine.

Comment: Don't see how there would be any approaches nicer than the provided approach. To some extend, the substitution can be simplified, but not by much.

Comment: So if $$f_0(x)= \sqrt{1+x}$$ and $$f_{n+1}(x)=\sqrt{1+f_n(x)}$$then you want to evaluate $$\int_{-1}^0 f_n(x) \operatorname d x$$ or $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_{-1}^0 f_n(x) \operatorname d x ? $$